# multi-entity aggregates event handling is not working

Tags: spring-boot, cqrs, axon

I have an aggregate root like this
it' creaditcard aggregates which have a records about payments,and ID, remit

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Log4j2
@Aggregate
public class CreditCard {

@AggregateIdentifier
private String id;

@AggregateMember
private List<CreditCardTransaction> transactions= new ArrayList<>();
private int limit; 
@CommandHandler
public CreditCard(CreditCardCreatedCmd cmd) {
    log.info(cmd.getId()+","+cmd.getLimit());
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(new CreditCardCreatedEvt(cmd.getId(), cmd.getLimit())); 
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(CreditCardCreatedEvt evt) {
    id = evt.getId();
    limit = evt.getLimit();
    log.info("[CreditCardCreatedEvt] id : "+id);

}

@CommandHandler
public void on(PaymentCmd cmd) throws LimitExceededException {

    if (limit < cmd.getValue())
        throw new LimitExceededException();
 
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(new PaymentSuccessEvt(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), cmd.getValue())); 

}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void handle(PaymentSuccessEvt evt) {
    log.info("[PaymentSuccessEvt] transactionId : "+evt.getTransactionId());
    transactions.add(new CreditCardTransaction(evt.getTransactionId(), evt.getValue()));
}

}
```

---

and child entity which have a payment's record

```
@Log4j2
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CreditCardTransaction {

    @EntityId
    private String transactionId;

    private int transactionValue;
    private boolean refund = false;

    private LocalDateTime paymentDate;

    public CreditCardTransaction(String transactionId, int transactionValue) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.transactionValue = transactionValue;
        this.paymentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public String getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void on(RefundCmd cmd) {

        if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(paymentDate, cmd.getToday()) >= 30)
            throw new DueTimeOverException();
       
        log.info("[RefundCmd] "+cmd.getTransactionId());
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new RefundEvt(cmd.getCardId(), cmd.getTransactionId()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void hanlde(RefundEvt evt) {
        if (transactionId.equals(evt.getTransactionId())) {
            transactionValue*=-1;
            paymentDate=LocalDateTime.now(); 
            refund = true;
            log.info("[RefundEvt accepted] transactionId : "+transactionId);
        }
        log.info("[RefundEvt rejected] transactionId : "+transactionId);
    }

}
```

---

```
@Data@NoArgsConstructor@AllArgsConstructor
public class RefundCmd {
    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    String cardId;
    String transactionId;
    LocalDateTime today;
}

@Data@NoArgsConstructor
public class RefundEvt {
    String cardId; 
    String transactionId; 
    LocalDateTime today;

    public RefundEvt(String cardId, String transactionId) {
        this.cardId = cardId;
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
        today=LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

when I'm sending command to my child entity like this

```
commandGateway.send(new RefundCmd(cardId, transactionId,LocalDateTime.now()));
```

that child entity's CommandHandler works but eventsourcinghandler can't get event

and I got exception like below

```
Command 'com.cqrs.order.demo.command.RefundCmd' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandExecutionException(Cannot request current Scope if none is 
active)
```

I'm doing this with reference to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-axon-multi-entity-aggregates).

Comment: Probably you need to change the aggregate identifier name to match the one in the aggregate and the command. Either name it cardId on the aggregate or call it id on the RefundCmd.

Comment: thanks for ur anwering but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when publishing events
use `org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateLifecycle.apply`
not `org.axonframework.commandhandling.model.AggregateLifecycle.apply`

Comment: Did you have a dependency to an old AxonFramework version?